# Electric potential of surface and volume charges?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

The definition of electric potential is$$
\mathbf{V(r)}=-\int_C \mathbf{E}\cdot \, d\mathbf{l}$$

Is this formula only for line charges?

What is the corresponding formulas for electric potentials of surfaces (cylinders) and volume charges (spheres)?

Comment: (1) I think we misunderstand something here : The curve of integration (open or closed) is not a curve with charges on it,  that is with line charge density, but any curve in space. So, your question about surfaces and volume charges has no sense.  
(2) This definition is valid for electrostatics $\:\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}=\boldsymbol{0}\:$. In electrodynamics  $\:\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}\ne\boldsymbol{0}\:$ this curve integral depends on the curve.

Answer (score 1):

The potential is not an absolute value, so what we have is the difference of potential between two points. That being said, the integral is not defined along the body producing the field, but along a path that connects two points, one of these points is a reference you adopt for the system, the other one is where you want to know the potential.

For example, for any finite object producing a field, you can define the reference point as the infinity with $V(\infty) \rightarrow 0$, so that the path of integration can be a line (or any other path) from infinity to the point you wanna know the potential, like:
\begin{equation}
V(\vec{r}) = - \int_\infty^{\vec{r}} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l}
\end{equation}

In the case of infinity objects $V(\infty) \neq 0$, so you have to choose another point of reference, and the above equation be
\begin{equation}
V(\vec{r}) - V( \vec{r_0}) = - \int_{\vec{r_0}}^{\vec{r}} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l}
\end{equation}
Just to answer the question, although I think you've realized, this is the equation of the potential for any body producing an electric field.